# Avoid insert multiple row in one to one relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa, annotations

I have one old entity and one new entity for expand old entity without modifications.

```
@Entity
public class OldEntity extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "activation_date")
    @NotNull
    private Instant activationDate;

      @OneToOne(mappedBy = "oldentity", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private NewEntity newEntity;

        // getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class NewEntity extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;


    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private OldEntity oldEntity;

// setters and getters

}
```

When i insert one row in newEntity table there aren't problems. But if i try to insert 2 row in table into newEntity when i call find i get, rightly, hibernate exception "More than one row with the given identifier was found".
Is it possible avoid multiple insert with standards hibernate annotations?

EDIT for insert new records i use simple repository like this

```
@Repository
public interface NewEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<NewRepository, Long> {

}
```

and in service i call

```
newEntityRepository.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get the objects from separate transactions, and try to save it. Then you can have this Exception. So the main point is transaction!

My suggestion.
**1. Use @Transaction annotation and wrap your entire logic in this method.**

```
@Trasactional
public void saveMethod() {
   NewEntity entity = new NewEntity();
   entity.setSomething(something);
   newEntitryRepository.save(entity);

   entity = newEntitryRepository.findById(entity.getId()).get();
   // do some other logic..
   newEntitryRepository.save(entity);
}
```

**2. Or you have complex business logic then add @Transaction to all your method called.**

```
@Transactional
public void saveMethod() {
    NewEntity entity = new NewEntity();
    entity.setSomething(something);
    newEntitryRepository.save(entity);
    saveMethodDetail();
}


@Transactional
public void saveMethodDetail(NewEntity entity) {
   entity = newEntitryRepository.findById(entity.getId()).get();
   // do some other logic..
   newEntitryRepository.save(entity);
}
```